# Treat '?' in LIKE query as literal

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have a search bar where a user can search for specific business's on a website. I need to be able to search for a company with a question mark in the name (either at the end, or elsewhere within.)

All my searches work, however, when I search for a company like: "My Company?" It throws an error saying the `?` is undefined. How can I escape it so that the query doesn't treat the `?` like a parameter?

```
exports.getEscapedQuery = function( params ) {
   // Using Sequelize w/ Node
   var escapedSearch = db.sequelize.escape( '%' + params.q + '%' );

   return escapedSearch;
};
```

Comment: Have you tried escaping ? by `\?`?

Comment: I have, it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Can you add the code that's performing the query?

Comment: It seemed to be a problem itself with the library I was using. I am using a workaround now, for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

If using Sequelize (like I am) it seems the current version's (2.2.2) sequelize.escape() method does not take kindly to `?` being present. In this case I was able to just remove the `?` from all search inputs before the query and it resolved my problem.